# How to measure time between incoming packages on an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, timing, data

For measuring the speed of incoming data packages on an FPGA, would you use a clock that is connected to a counter and each time a package is detected, it would store the time?

And if there would be a difference between your expected time, you would set a flag?

And could you also count the times where it exceeded your expected time?

And could you also add markers inside the packages in the sending device, so that the receiving device can measure the markers and see if the time gap is in an expected range?

Comment: I would do whatever is appropriate for the application. If it would be useful to count the times where the actual time exceeds the expected time, I would do that. It it wouldn't be useful, then I would not do it.

Answer (score 1):

> For measuring the speed of incoming data packages on an FPGA, would you use a clock that is connected to a counter and each time a package is detected, it would store the time?

If your questions is **speed** of transmission (**as in your question text**):

Why would you store the time? You would just increase a register containing the count. After a defined amount of time has elapsed, you would then inspect the counter, and count / duration == rate.

If you just care about **duration between two packets** (**as in your question title**):

Why would you store the time? You just enable a counter that counts clock edges, until you disable it with the next packet. count == duration.